# How do I add a small Popover with Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I need to add a button that drops down a small pop-over view. How do I go about doing this using Forms so it is cross-platform?

**Update:**

Based on the suggestion of trying XLabs' PopupLayout, I've been trying to get it to work. Now I'm getting a runtime error saying:

Position 14:4. Type popup:PopupLayout not found in xmlns clr-namespace:XLabs.Forms.Controls;assembly=ACS.FundRaising

My XAML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
            x:Class="ACS.FundRaising.Views.TransactionsView" 
            xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:ACS.FundRaising.ViewModels;assembly=ACS.FundRaising" 
            xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ACS.FundRaising.Controls;assembly=ACS.FundRaising" 
            xmlns:popup="clr-namespace:XLabs.Forms.Controls;assembly=ACS.FundRaising"
            Padding="0,0,0,0" 
            BackgroundColor="#f6f6f6">

<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <viewModels:TransactionsViewModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <popup:PopupLayout x:Name="_PopupLayout">
        <popup:PopupLayout.Content>
.
.
.
        </popup:PopupLayout.Content>
    </popup:PopupLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

If I try to instantiate a copy of PopupLayout in code, I don't get any error.

Comment: You could accomplish something similar with: https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Forms/XLabs.Forms/Controls/PopupLayout.cs

Comment: @DanielLuberda Thanks. Wrestling with it now.

Comment: You have a wrong assembly specified. It should be xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:XLabs.Forms.Controls;assembly=XLabs.Forms"

Comment: @DanielLuberda Thanks. Perhaps I'll try another time. For now I decided to go with an Action Sheet.